# JavaFX, автообновление приложения

Tags: java, javafx, обновление

Имеется javaFX приложение, облачное хранилище и mySql бд.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать функционал, при котором приложение по нажатию пользователем кнопки сверяется свою версию(значение зашитое в самом приложении) с версией из бд, и в случае расхождения обновляет себя в рантайме? С чего начать? Не нагуглил ничего толком.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. Самостоятельное обновление
2. Использование лаунчера (небольшая программа, главной задачей
   которой является проверка версии основного приложения, скачивание
   обновлений, обновление и запуск)

Первая половина в обоих случаях одинаковая:

- узнать версию (не обязательно из базы)
- скачать файлы с новой версией, например в папку update. Источник так же может быть различным: ftp, локальная сеть и т.д.

Отличие только в том, где располагается этот код: либо в самом приложении, либо в лаунчере.

Вторая половина уже отличается:

Лаунчер - просто заменить файлы, почистить за собой и запустить (используя стандартные средства Java для работы с файлами).

Само приложение:

- Определить ОС (Windows, Unix...)
- Создать скрипт (bat, sh...). Задача скрипта перенести файлы с папки update на основные места файлов приложений. Последняя строка в скрипте - запуск самого приложения с некоторым аргументом (например, -noupdate) (что бы снова обновы не проверял) (Обычное создание файла с некоторым содержимым)
- Запустить скрип через `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`
- Закрыть приложение. (Скрип не будет выполняться, пока приложение открыто, т.к. файлы заняты).

Так же желательно предусмотреть в скрипте команды для сокрытия (например, `@echo off`).

Запуск приложения без консоли (`@start javaw -jar`) что бы после запуска приложения не висело консольное окно.

Comment: Если пойдете по пути лаунчера, то есть готовый проект getdown. Он сравнивает хеши файлов проекта, выкачивает те что не совпадают и запускает приложение.